# Morocco visa from Berlin

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, germany, morocco

Did anyone visit Morocco? I would like to visit the country but I can not find any information related to visa application requirement in their website http://www.botschaft-marokko.de/. If anyone visited before please let me know where can I get the details and how to apply for visa. I am not German citizen btw. Also, I have to apply from Berlin embassy since I live in Berlin.

Comment: And your citizenship is?

Comment: I have Indian citizenship.

Answer (score 2):

Consulates issue visas, not Embassies (some Embassies have also a Consulate department).

From your linked page, press

- **Das Konsulat**

Go down to:

- Marokko entdecken - Touristenvisum, Studentenvisum, Geschäftsvisum

  - press [Einsehen](https://www.consulat.ma/de/visaarten)

There you will find information about the Visa types and a PDF form as Visa application.

Fees (Page in French)

Up to 3 months:

- single entry € 220
- multiple entries € 330

---

**Sources**:

- [Visaarten | Konsularischen Dienste](https://www.consulat.ma/de/visaarten)